# react material-ui icons breaking in production build

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, material-ui

I have a react app in which I am wrapping the entire app with material-ui. In the optimised deployment build (obtained by running `$ npm run build`) the material-ui icons are breaking (all the icons are getting a white background and the color of the icon defaults to black). When the page is loaded initially everything looks fine and the icons are displayed as expected, but they break once react-router renders another page.

I tried changing the nesting level of `<MuiThemeProvider>` tag but it didn't work out.

my **index.js** looks something like

`

```
const app =(
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={muitheme}>
        <Provider store={store}>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <App />
            </BrowserRouter>
        </Provider>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
 );
ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById('root'));
```

my **app.js**is wrapped in two Higher Order Components like this.

`export default withRouter( connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(App));`

the expected icon looks like 
[image]

and the broken icon looks like [image]

Comment: Do you have a minimal reproducible example? Something on codesandbox would be helpful.

Comment: @JoshWooding actually the flow is too complex to be added to codesandbox. To help you get the proper Idea of the issue I am sharing my firebase deployment of the project [my project's deployment](https://react-burger-builder-3bcfe.firebaseapp.com/). also you could look at complete code in [git](https://gitlab.com/yerqueri/react-burger-builder)

Comment: Sorry it's taken so long, my initial guess without changing anything is a version mismatch between @material-ui/icons and material-ui. I would either use the new version (`@material-ui/core` and `@material-ui/icons`)  or use the old version (`material-ui` and `material-ui-icons`) but not mix them.